# Helm getting :at <.Values.serviceAccount.create>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.create

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have simple helm which I try to run but I'm getting error when doing `lint/tamplate --debug`.

The error:

```
vagrant@ubuntu2010:~/java/projects$ helm template --debug ./message-server-helm
install.go:214: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:231: [debug] CHART PATH: /home/vagrant/java/projects/message-server-helm


Error: template: message-server-helm/templates/serviceaccount.yaml:1:14: executing "message-server-helm/templates/serviceaccount.yaml" at <.Values.serviceAccount.create>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.create
helm.go:84: [debug] template: message-server-helm/templates/serviceaccount.yaml:1:14: executing "message-server-helm/templates/serviceaccount.yaml" at <.Values.serviceAccount.create>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.create
```

Where the chart files are:

chart.yaml

```
apiVersion: v2
name: message-server-helm
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
```

values.yaml

```
replicaCount: 1
image:
  repository: "docker-message-server"
  tag: "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
service:
  type: NodePort
  port: 80
```

deployment.yaml

```
piVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "message-server-helm.fullname" . }}
  labels:
pp.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "message-server-helm.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "message-server-helm.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "message-server-helm.name" . }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "message-server-helm.name" . }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "message-server-helm.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "message-server-helm.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "message-server-helm.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}                                                                                                                                                                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "message-server-helm.name" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

serviceaccount.yaml

```
{{- if .Values.serviceAccount.create -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{ include "message-server-helm.serviceAccountName" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "message-server-helm.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.serviceAccount.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
automountServiceAccountToken: {{ .Values.serviceAccount.automount }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: The error message says that `serviceAccount` isn't present in the Helm values (that is, your `values.yaml` file).  Do you need to add it?  Do the things in `serviceaccount.yaml` actually need to be configurable?  Or do you need to tolerate it maybe not being present?